Induction over multiple arguments in Isabelle
Exercise 2.11 of "Concrete Semantics" by Tobias Nipkow, Gerwin Klein asks to define polynomials as lists of coefficients, I defined addition as matching over two parameters:
theory PolyList
  imports Main
begin

fun evalp :: "int list ⇒ int ⇒ int" where
"evalp Nil y = 0" |
"evalp (Cons x xs) y = (evalp xs y) * y + x"

value "evalp [3, 2, 1] 2"     (* 11 = 3 + 2*2 + 1*2^2*)

fun addp :: "int list ⇒ int list ⇒ int list" where
"addp Nil ys = ys" |
"addp xs Nil = xs" |
"addp (x#xs) (y#ys) = (x+y)#(addp xs ys)"

value "addp [1::int, 10, 100] [2, 30]"  (* 3 + 40*x + 100*x^2 *)

Now I want to prove some fact using apply(induction) tactic but I don't know syntax for induction over two parameters (xp & yp), for a single parameter it is apply(induction xp)... The theorem is:
lemma evalp_addp[simp]: "evalp (addp px py) v = (evalp px v) + (evalp py v)"
  apply(induction ???)

After some experimentation I succeeded with syntax:
  apply(induction rule: addp.induct)
  apply(auto simp add: algebra_simps)

But I still wonder if it is possible to specify variable names, like apply(induction xp & yp) - for the cases where I need to be more specific about induction location...

Yes, you can specify variable names.
In cases where you have an induction rule referring to multiple variables, you just list them before the rule statement (without commas or other tokens).
In your example, this would read:
apply (induction px py rule: addp.induct)

This already is what Isabelle guesses.
So, it makes no difference.
(But other instantiations, e.g. induction py px rule: addp.induct would indeed change (and break) the proof.)
The right induction rule
Isabelle selects some fitting induction rule depending on context.
Isabelle will usually try some induction on an inductive datatype of a variable appearing in the goal.
Other rules on inductive predicates make sense when you have something that allows induction in the premises.
In your example, there are no premises, so, per default, we're talking about datatype induction.
We cannot just write apply (induction px py) as the standard induction on lists only uses one variable.
However, there are some predefined induction schemes to work on two lists, but we have to name their rules explicitly.
In this case list_induct2', would work:
thm list_induct2'

?P [] [] ⟹
(⋀x xs. ?P (x # xs) []) ⟹
(⋀y ys. ?P [] (y # ys)) ⟹
(⋀x xs y ys. ?P xs ys ⟹ ?P (x # xs) (y # ys)) ⟹
?P ?xs ?ys

So, “ideomatically”, your proof could read:
  apply (induction px py rule: list_induct2')
  by (auto simp add: algebra_simps)

(Again, we could drop the px py.)
The rule, you chose, addp.induct is an induction scheme that is automatically created by fun.
As the fun command proves termination of addp, we know that one can also induct on the recursion structure appearing in addp.
Note that addp itself plays no role in addp.induct.
But, as in your case, these fun-generated induction rules often work well if their function appears in the context of a goal.
Multiple variables in mutual induction
For completeness, I want to mention another case, which is not relevant to the specific scenario in this question, but also involves multiple variables:
When one introduces mutually recursive datatypes or functions, one often inducts over a bunch of implications with variables of different types.
In this case, one has to put and between the listed variables of the mutual recursion.
The shortest, quite contrived, example I could come up with is:
datatype
  even = SucE odd | Zero and
  odd = SucO even

thm even_odd.induct

fun toNatE and toNatO
  where ‹toNatE Zero = 0›
  | ‹toNatE (SucE od) = Suc (toNatO od)›
  | ‹toNatO (SucO e) = Suc (toNatE e)›

lemma
  ‹even (toNatE e)›
  ‹odd (toNatO od)›
  apply (induct e and od)
  (* state
    1. ⋀x. odd (toNatO x) ⟹ even (toNatE (SucE x))
    2. even (toNatE Zero)
    3. ⋀x. even (toNatE x) ⟹ odd (toNatO (SucO x))
  *)
  by auto

(In particular, apply (induct e od) would fail here.)
